# Constant current LED driver temperature issue

Tags: pcb-design, led-driver, constant-current, step-down

I am using a DC-DC step-down constant current LED driver to power up four high power LEDs in a series connection. The LEDs are drawing a 2 A current at 100% power and they have forward voltage about 26 V.

The driver is [AL8843](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL8843.pdf) and it is working very well, except that the driver/[freewheeling diode](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Shandong-Jingdao-Microelectronics-SS310_C116705.pdf) or [inductor](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2008102134_YJYCOIN-YSPI0740-330M_C718398.pdf) (I think the driver first and then diode and inductor but I am not sure, maybe all of them) are getting hot to even above ~100°C or more in less than several seconds, but they're also cooling very fast when I turn off the driver.

The schematic are shown below.
[image]

I've choose external components based on datasheet and design calculator provided by chip manufacturer. Theoretical peak inductor current is 2.2 A and my inductor's rated current is 2.5 A which could be a little bit too low?

I am also worried about my PCB layout which seems to have few things to improve, but I am curious that it could result in such a bad thermal issue?

[image]

I know that the switching node copper pour is way too big and the inductor is far away from the SW pins, but can it cause the temperature rise?

[image]

[image]

I'm also wondering what the purpose of the vias is on the [reference design](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Evaluation-Boards/AL8843EV1-User-Guide.pdf) marked with the green. It is for thermal dissipation?

[image]

Comment: Probe the SW pin with your oscilloscope. 2.2 out of 2.5 A is a bit close, but either run a current probe on that node or if you don't have one, a low value resistor in series with two probes and the math function on your scope and check to make sure you're not saturating it.

Comment: Yes, those vias are for heat dissipation and carry heat to the (presumably) large track on the other side. Have you soldered the pad on the bottom of your AL8843?